Multimodal architecture: how to train it
I have a set of graphs, a set of sequences and a set of summary stats, the elements in the three sets correspond to each other. I am not satisfied with the regression performance from one single dataset using one single model, so I am interested in whether I can leverage all of them. I constructed a model like this (pseudo code PyTorch):
GNN(...) # Graph neural network, process graph
DNN(...) # Fully connected linear layers, process stats
LSTM(...) # process sequences or time series

# Then bundle them together:
class MultiModal(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):

            self.gnn = GNN(...)
            self.dnn = DNN(...)
            self.lstm = LSTM(...)

            # Final Readout Layers
            self.lin1 = torch.nn.Linear(...)
            self.lin2 = torch.nn.Linear(..., number_of_predicted_values)

        def forward(self, graph, stats, seqs):
            x1 = self.gnn(graph)
            x2 = self.dnn(stats)
            x3 = self.lstm(seqs)

            # Concatenate features
            x = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3)
            x = self.lin1(x)
            x = F.gelu(x)
            x = F.dropout(x)
            x = self.lin2(x)

            return x

Can I feed corresponding data altogether to this combined model and train it just as training a single model like GNN or DNN or LSTM? Will optimizer like Adam work properly? Would it be better to just train three models separately and then take the mean predictions?
